# Why php session is not a value but blank in my login page

Tags: php, session

In my project, i have a login page with verification code.

Some verification code of login page is like:

```
<form class="form-login" action="index.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="code" class="form-control" placeholder="verification code">
<img id="codeImg" src="create_code.php" alt="not clear, another" style="cursor: pointer; vertical-align:middle" onClick="create_code()">
 </form>
```

In create_code.php, some code about creating verification code is like:

```
session_start();
header("Content-type: image/png");
$str = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,a,b,c,d,f,g";
$list = explode(",", $str);
$cmax = count($list) - 1;
$verifyCode = '';
for ( $i=0; $i < 5; $i++ ){
      $randnum = mt_rand(0, $cmax);
      $verifyCode .= $list[$randnum];
}
$_SESSION['code'] = $verifyCode; // stor verifycode in session
```

In index.php, I need to check the inpu verifycode and session verifycode, some code is like:

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_GET['log_out']) && ($_POST['code'] != $_SESSION['code']))
{
    echo "verifycode is wrong！<br />" . "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='2;url=index.html'>";
    die();
}
```

But unlucky, it is fail. I have found there is nothing in $_SESSION['code']。$_SESSION['code'] should be a value, but a blank instead.

besides, it worked OK a few days ago, but it fails today. I have no changed any code, it seems nothing wrong, who can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem。 My Linux server disk space is 100%. When I deleted some files, it works Ok. Is there  some session log file can print prompt message ?